# Parsing query parameters that contains square brackets in spring boot as a map

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently working on rewriting the backend of a PHP Symfony application with Spring boot. I cannot touch the front-end code, and have to modify my backend to work in accordance with existing request structure.
However, I am currently stuck with something that i need some help with

some examples of an endpoint looks as below

```
/app/api/incidents?customSearch=Some reason&dt=month&order[timeStart]=desc
/app/api/incidents?customSearch=Some reason&dt=month&order[timeResolved]=desc
```

How can I map these endpoints to my RestController as a Map ? as per latest tomcat configuration square brackets are not valid and hence unsupported, throwing a 400 error. Adding a configuration for tomcat to support these characters, resolves the issue.
But how can I map the above request params into an order hashmap ?
There are other parameters that needs to be mapped as well
e.g. timeStart

```
/app/api/incidents?timeStart[after]=2022-10-11 00:00:00&timeStart[before]=2022-10-13 23:59:59&dt=range&order[incidentSeverity.orderBy]=desc
```

based on these values, the corresponding query needs to be formed.

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestParam(name = "order") Map<String, String> order) {
        log.info("order : " + order);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }
```

But order is mapped to null

Can anyone please help me with this. I have already wasted way more time than I should have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because of `name` in `(@RequestParam(name = "order")`. Spring boot tries to bind a request parameter named `order` when you put `name` not the whole map. You should remove `name`to accept all parameters to a map.

```java
   @GetMapping
   public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> order) {
       log.info("order : " + order);
       return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should not be the code you have but the `url` that you send that is broken in an earlier place

```
/app/api/incidents?customSearch=Some reason&dt=month&order[timeStart]=desc
```

Try with

```
/app/api/incidents?customSearch=Some%20reason&dt=month&order[timeStart]=desc
```

you should normally encode empty spaces in query parameter values.